# Execute scripts AJAX returns

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, return, alert

TIP: "you could simple send an json object / array from php to js, and execute every entry like "update_match('1');" using the eval() function, please stop sending js code that way"- Lucian Depold.

---

In the index.php, I have this code, which executes when the document is ready:

```
$.post('php/main.php', {elements: 1}, function(return_msg) {
    alert(return_msg);
});
```

The respond I get is a bunch of scripts, as expected, with the expected values. However, they do not execute! How to make them execute?

Here is the response:

```
<script>jsfunction(37069);</script><script>updateTextbox('');</script><script>update_match('1', '19.30 Friday 15/5', '1');</script><script>update_player('1', '1', 'recoba', 'cmf', 'teo', '0', '0');</script><script>update_player('1', '2', 'nesta', 'cb', 'tsoulou', '0', '0');</script><script>update_player('1', '3', 'raul', 'cf', 'striker', '0', '0');</script><script>update_player('1', '4', 'samuel', 'cb', 'mafia', '', '1');</script><script>update_player('1', '5', 'deisler', 'cmf', 'free_kick', '1', '');</script><script>update_player('1', '6', 'ferdinard', 'cb', 'strong', '1', '');</script><script>update_match('2', 'Match 2', '0');</script>
```

When I had the PHP code that produced these scripts in the bottom of the index.php, all the js functions where called correctly. Because of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32554248/cant-get-global-variable/32554401#32554401) though, I had to move the code to another .php file.

Comment: you want js code returned via ajax to run ?

Comment: Yes @Dagon, but I think I got the answer.

Comment: all good, just need clarification

Comment: are you sending all those "<script>" tags over ajax and execute them ???

Comment: i don't think this is a great approach, i cant see why you cant call the js the 'usual' way - it does seem to be all the same site after all

Comment: Yes @LucianDepold, how else could I execute a js function, with PHP ariables?

Comment: there are other ways to execute js code. take a look at the eval function: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp

Comment: Still @LucianDepold, I can't see how eval will help here.

Comment: you could simply send an json object / array from php to js, and execute every entry like "update_match('1');" using the eval() function, please stop sending js code that way

Comment: Good idea @LucianDepold, thanks! I liked it so much I upvoted your top answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it this way:

In PHP...

```
$arrayOfCalls = array();
$arrayOfCalls[]="update_match('1')";
$arrayOfCalls[]="update_match('2')";

$dummy = array();
$dummy['calls'] =$arrayOfCalls;
echo json_encode($dummy);
```

And in Javascript...

```
$.post('php/main.php', {elements: 1}, function(return_json) {
    return_json = JSON.parse(return_json);
    return_json.calls.forEach(function(code){
    eval(code);
    })
});
```

Comment: Don't we need to specify in the post call that the data we sent are of JSON format?

Comment: the data you send to php, or from php to js ?

Comment: From php to js. Also, shouldn't we use a semicolon after the parenthesis, after the `eval()` call?

Comment: you could specify the fourth parameter as JSON, but jquery takes an "intelligent guess" (http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/). i think it should work without.

Comment: Good. I am getting this error: `Uncaught TypeError: return_json.forEach is not a function`

Comment: could you console.log the return_json, maybe it is an object not an array.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89530/discussion-between-lucian-depold-and-gsamaras).

Comment: I had it working with: `$.post('php/main.php', {elements: 1}, function(return_json) {
   //console.log(return_json);
   return_json = JSON.parse(return_json);
   return_json.calls.forEach(function(code){
    eval(code);
   })
  });`

Comment: maybe the fourth parameter would also have done the trick, setting it to "JSON"...

Answer (score 1):

You can append the result to your page :

```
$.post('php/main.php', {elements: 1}, function(return_msg) {
    $('body').append(return_msg);
});
```

The code will be executed but I'm not sure if it's safe to do that.

Answer (score 1):

The date delivered by the AJAX call is just data - or text. In order to interpret that as JavaScript, you must append it to the dom.

Two ways: 
first, by appending the data directly:

```
$.post('php/main.php', {elements: 1}, function(return_msg) {
    alert(return_msg);
    $('body').append(return_msg);
});
```

but there's also a [shorthand method](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/):

```
$.getScript('php/main.php?elements=' + 1, function () {
   // script loaded

});
```

Please read the docs, there are some caveats!

Comment: Thanks! +1 for the shorthand method.