# Why I get undefined when I try to use an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I created a classical Array

```
Gpx_Array = new Array;
```

In another function I dinamically populate my Array

```
Gpx_Array.push(coords);
```

Problems starting when Array is back to main function: if I check it with

```
console.log(Gpx_Array);
```

```
[]
0:(588) [M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, …]
1:(819) [M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M, …]
length:2
[[Prototype]]:Array(0)
```

but using

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(Gpx_Array, null, 2));
```

I get just [ ],

When I try to access

```
console.log(Gpx_Array[0]);
```

I get 'undefinded'

Why I can't go inside array, especially as I can see it with

```
console.log(Gpx_Array);
```

If I go on console browser, right click on array result and copy object I get exacly what I need (I post only a part)

```
[
[{"lat":46.204669,"lng":13.347643,"meta":{"ele":"687.5"}},
{"lat":46.204666,"lng":13.347667,"meta":{"ele":"685.2"}},
{"lat":46.20467,"lng":13.347719,"meta":{"ele":"684.5"}},
{"lat":46.204691,"lng":13.347817,"meta":{"ele":"684.1"}},
{"lat":46.204706,"lng":13.347858,"meta":{"ele":"683.9"}},
...],
[
{"lat":46.484188,"lng":12.865198,"meta":{"ele":"527.8"}},
{"lat":46.484205,"lng":12.865215,"meta":{"ele":"528.2"}},
{"lat":46.484231,"lng":12.865284,"meta":{"ele":"528.3"}},
{"lat":46.48424,"lng":12.865375,"meta":{"ele":"528.3"}},
{"lat":46.484217,"lng":12.865452,"meta":{"ele":"528.5"}},
...
]
]
```

I tried even strange solutions like

Gpx_Array[], Gpx_Array[][0], Gpx_Array[""]... Without any benefit.

Following is function I use.
It's a Leaflet plugin
https://github.com/shramov/leaflet-plugins
that is useful in my case, as load data directly from gpx file

```
L.GPX = L.FeatureGroup.extend({
    initialize: function (gpx, options) {
        L.Util.setOptions(this, options);
        this._gpx = gpx;
        this._layers = {};

        if (gpx) {
            this.addGPX(gpx, options, this.options.async);
        }
    },

    loadXML: function (url, cb, options, async) {
        if (async === undefined) async = this.options.async;
        if (options === undefined) options = this.options;

        var req = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
        req.open('GET', url, async);
        try {
            req.overrideMimeType('text/xml'); // unsupported by IE
        } catch (e) {}
        req.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (req.readyState !== 4) return;
            if (req.status === 200) cb(req.responseXML, options);
        };
        req.send(null);
    },

    _humanLen: function (l) {
        if (l < 2000)
            return l.toFixed(0) + ' m';
        else
            return (l/1000).toFixed(1) + ' km';
    },

    _polylineLen: function (line)//line is a L.Polyline()
    {
        var ll = line._latlngs;
        var d = 0, p = null;
        for (var i = 0; i < ll.length; i++)
        {
            if (i && p)
                d += p.distanceTo(ll[i]);
            p = ll[i];
        }
        return d;
    },

    addGPX: function (url, options, async) {
        var _this = this;
        var cb = function (gpx, options) { _this._addGPX(gpx, options); };
        this.loadXML(url, cb, options, async);
    },

    _addGPX: function (gpx, options) {
        var layers = this.parseGPX(gpx, options);
        if (!layers) return;
        this.addLayer(layers);
        this.fire('loaded');
    },

    parseGPX: function (xml, options) {
        var j, i, el, layers = [];
        var named = false, tags = [['rte','rtept'], ['trkseg','trkpt']];

        for (j = 0; j < tags.length; j++) {
            el = xml.getElementsByTagName(tags[j][0]);
            for (i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
                var l = this.parse_trkseg(el[i], xml, options, tags[j][1]);
                for (var k = 0; k < l.length; k++) {
                    if (this.parse_name(el[i], l[k])) named = true;
                    layers.push(l[k]);
                }
            }
        }

        el = xml.getElementsByTagName('wpt');
        if (options.display_wpt !== false) {
            for (i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
                var marker = this.parse_wpt(el[i], xml, options);
                if (!marker) continue;
                if (this.parse_name(el[i], marker)) named = true;
                layers.push(marker);
            }
        }

        if (!layers.length) return;
        var layer = layers[0];
        if (layers.length > 1)
            layer = new L.FeatureGroup(layers);
        if (!named) this.parse_name(xml, layer);
        return layer;
    },

    parse_name: function (xml, layer) {
        var i, el, txt='', name, descr='', link, len=0;
        el = xml.getElementsByTagName('name');
        if (el.length)
            name = el[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        el = xml.getElementsByTagName('desc');
        for (i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
            for (var j = 0; j < el[i].childNodes.length; j++)
                descr = descr + el[i].childNodes[j].nodeValue;
        }
        el = xml.getElementsByTagName('link');
        if (el.length)
            link = el[0].getAttribute('href');

        if (layer instanceof L.Path)
            len = this._polylineLen(layer);

        if (name) txt += '<h2>' + name + '</h2>' + descr;
        if (len) txt += '<p>' + this._humanLen(len) + '</p>';
        if (link) txt += '<p><a target="_blank" href="'+link+'">[...]</a></p>';

        if (layer && layer._popup === undefined) layer.bindPopup(txt);
        return txt;
    },

    parse_trkseg: function (line, xml, options, tag) {
        var el = line.getElementsByTagName(tag);
        if (!el.length) return [];
        var coords = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
            var ll = new L.LatLng(el[i].getAttribute('lat'),
                        el[i].getAttribute('lon'));
            ll.meta = {};
            for (var j in el[i].childNodes) {
                var e = el[i].childNodes[j];
                if (!e.tagName) continue;
                ll.meta[e.tagName] = e.textContent;
            }
            coords.push(ll);
        }
        var l = [new L.Polyline(coords, options)];


//      Gpx_Array.push(coords);


++contatore;

switch (contatore) {
    case 1:
        var coordinate_gpx_01=coords
        localStorage.setItem("coordinate_gpx_01",coords);
        break;
    case 2:
        var coordinate_gpx_02=coords
        localStorage.setItem("coordinate_gpx_02",coords);
        break;
    default:

}
console.log(contatore);

    //  var coordinate_gpx=coords
    //  localStorage.setItem("coordinate_gpx",coords);



        this.fire('addline', {line:l});
        return l;
    },

    parse_wpt: function (e, xml, options) {
        var m = new L.Marker(new L.LatLng(e.getAttribute('lat'),
                        e.getAttribute('lon')), options);
        var attributes = {};
        for (var i = 0; i < e.childNodes.length; i++) {
            var ch = e.childNodes[i];
            if (ch.nodeName !== '#text') {
                attributes[ch.nodeName] = ch.textContent;
            }
        }
        this.fire('addpoint', {point:m, attributes:attributes});
        return m;
    }
});
```

Function is called with following string

```
var track = new L.GPX('tracce_gpx/Ovaro(MonteZoncolan)_Sutrio.gpx', {async: true,   display_wpt:false, color:'#f5f5de',opacity:0.4,weight:6}).on('click', function(e){var popup_video = L.popup().setLatLng(e.latlng).setContent('<div><iframe class="video_back" width="280" height="160" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/UN5IiFt1udE?rel=0&vq=small" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share" allowfullscreen></iframe><button type="button" class="pop btn btn-default" title="" ><a target="_blank" href="percorsi/Ovaro(MonteZoncolan)_Sutrio.gpx"><i class="fa fa-download" aria-hidden="true"></i> .GPX</a></button></div>').openOn(mappa_percorsi);}).addTo(Video);
```

I found a solution that works, but it's far to be nice or performant, but works.

I set a counter in Main function, and in secondary function, I added this part of code

```
++contatore;

switch (contatore) {
    case 1:
        var coordinate_gpx_01=coords
        localStorage.setItem("coordinate_gpx_01",coords);
        break;
    case 2:
        var coordinate_gpx_02=coords
        localStorage.setItem("coordinate_gpx_02",coords);
        break;
    default:
}
```

Then in main function I get var value with

```
let originale_01=localStorage.getItem("coordinate_gpx_01");

let originale_02=localStorage.getItem("coordinate_gpx_02");
```

As said it works, but hope to find a better and elegant solution with array, as I have to repeat part of code 50 or 60 times.

Any suggestion is wellcome, thanks in advance

Comment: Is your function async? The console in many browsers logs live objects which update as they are mutated. It sounds like you are returning from an async function without awaiting.

Comment: @pilchard probably you are right, but I placed console log at end of my final function, to avoid interferences.

Comment: where is `coords` coming from? If you post your actual functions we may be able to help, but as it is there isn't enough context.

Comment: Modified question adding function used.

Comment: Thank you for adding additional information. It is still unclear how you are using it, but perhaps look at the [GPX Example](https://github.com/shramov/leaflet-plugins/blob/master/examples/gpx.html) provided by the plugin docs. You'll note that the coordinates are fetched using an `async` initializer, and then multiple listeners are added to handle the data as it arrives.

Comment: added "launcing code" and confirm that is async

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if I did't solved problem, probably I found best solution awailable with my skills and my needings

In Main file I added this lines

```
  contatore = 0;

  for ( var i = 0; i< 50; i++ ) {
     window[ "giro_dati_gpx" + i ] = "";
  }
```

A counter and a bounch of variables generated dinamically.
In secondary file, that generates my data, I modified with this

```
 ++contatore;
 window[ "giro_dati_gpx" + contatore ]=coords
 localStorage.setItem(window[ "giro_dati_gpx" + contatore ],coords);
```

So every time this function runs, dinamically load a different variable and give new value.
When control go back to Main function, using this part of code I get my data and finally I can use them as I wanted

```
for ( let contatore_gpx = 1; contatore_gpx < contatore; contatore_gpx++ ) {

  let originale=localStorage.getItem(window[ "giro_dati_gpx" + contatore_gpx ]);
  let LatLong_completo = JSON.parse('[' + originale.replaceAll('LatLng(', '[').replaceAll(')', ']') + ']')
  string = String(originale);
  result = countString(string, letterToCheck);
  numero = Math.round(result / 14);
  mysequence_color = rainbow(numero);
  var polyline = L.polycolor(LatLong_completo, {colors: mysequence_color, weight: 5 }).addTo(Video);

}
```

For the moment I'm satisfied, but I continue to wait to know why using an
array I can't get same data that I can use with a variable.

Thanks for help given

Comment: following https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32554248/cant-get-global-variable I get a solution setting a timeout, so I intercepted result of my async function call

Answer (score 0):

If I implement the code based on your instruction, then it behaves properly in my case. Therefore the issue is something related with your implementation that you do not share with us. See:

```js
function first() {
    let Gpx_Array = new Array;
    second(Gpx_Array);
    console.log(Gpx_Array);
}

function second(Gpx_Array) {
    for (let coords = 1; coords < 4; coords++) Gpx_Array.push({lat: coords, long: coords});
}

first();
```

Comment: This should be a comment asking for debugging details, or flag as not reproducible.

Comment: @pilchard in my opinion it is vital information that this is expected to work. Visitors to this question would be discouraged from using the syntax shown there.

Answer (score -1):

You have to use

```
Gpx_Array = new Array();
```

As it is a class and it needs to be instantiated before it can be used.
You can also use:

```
Gpx_Array = [];
```

Which automatically creates a new Array object

Comment: When using the [`new`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new#syntax) operator Javascript allows omitting the parentheses if there are no arguments passed.

Comment: Have you actually tried to use `new Array`?

Comment: tryied both solutions shown above, but no changes.